# background color is not applying for multiple rows for kendoGrid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

i have written this line of code for setting row background color

`$("#gridSellIn tbody tr:first").addClass('rowColor');`.

It's working fine for first row of grid, but i need to apply this color to 3,12,16 rows. What i need to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$("#gridSellIn tbody tr:eq(0)").addClass('rowColor');
$("#gridSellIn tbody tr:eq(2)").addClass('rowColor')
$("#gridSellIn tbody tr:eq(11)").addClass('rowColor')
$("#gridSellIn tbody tr:eq(15)").addClass('rowColor')
```

Thanks

Comment: I suggest to compress this piece of code with : `$("#gridSellIn tbody").find("tr:eq(0), tr:eq(2), tr:eq(11), tr:eq(15)").addClass('rowColor');`.